# Solving 6th order equation numerically

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function called f(v,e,s). It is sixth order in s. I want to find solutions for s for the equation: f(v,e,s)=0.
It is clear that to solve the equation numerically, Mathematica needs to know e and v. I want to change v and e in two different intervals. e is changing from 0 to 1 by Stepsize equal to 0.01 and v changes from zero to 4 by stepsize equal to 0.1.

one could find the solution for the equation as:

```
Solve[f==0,s];
```

but to know the solution completely, one needs to know e and v, then he can use N[%] to find the solution. Is there any way of find a table of solutions for e and v changing in the interval I mentioned before?
Any answers with an example s highly appreciated.

Comment: Check documentation for `Table` and `NSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

An example function:

```
f[v_, e_, s_] = ((v + 1) s - e)^6
```

And then use Table with NSolve to solve for various values of e and v:

```
Table[(s /. NSolve[f[v, e, s] == 0, s]), {e, 0, 1, 0.01}, {v, 0, 4, 0.1}]
```

Comment: How can I do this for different solutions of NSolve? Forexample  I want to do that for the third solution?

Comment: What is the third solution? This is giving all 6 roots. You could order them by magnitude (baring in mind they may be complex) by using Sort.

Comment: I want to use listdensityplot to plot real part of 6 different solutions in six different plots. Axises of plots are v and e. Could you help me please?

Comment: I added the code I try to the question, I used the same code for other solutions by changing the last argument of part. But I think it sometimes shows the same solution twice.Because sometimes some graphs become the same.

Comment: The code I used to show real part of frst solution is:

 datas1r = Flatten[Table[{v, e, 
 ComplexExpand@
  Re@ Part[(s /. NSolve[f[v, e, s] == 0, s]), 1]}, {v, 0, 20, 
 0.1}, {e, 1/(15 ro) + 0.01, 4, 0.01}], 1];ListDensityPlot[datas1r, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[Sigma]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]