# ListDensity plot with negative regions in red

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How can one makes ListDensityPlot which shows negative regions in a certain color for example red?

```
ListDensityPlot[ddatas1r, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["U_0", Large]}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[Sigma]", LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Comment: You can supply your own color function with the `ColorFunction` option.

Comment: The problem is , I don't know how to tell it that negative regions should be red. Note the 'negative region'. I added my code @C.E.

Comment: You can make your own color function. Please review the documentation of `ColorFunction` to see how this is done. If you can't make it work, then post your attempt at making a custom color function.

Comment: Note that by default the `ColorFunction` is fed a normalized value in range `0-1`. For this you will need to use option `ColorFunctionScaling->False` so that it sees your actual data value.

Comment: You mean I should add ColorFunctionScaling->False after ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow" in the code? @george2079

Comment: ColorFunctionScaling -> False doesn't separete negative values @george2079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need `ColorFunctionScaling->False` and a color function that treats negative values specially:

```
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[Table[{x, y, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] - 1/2} ,
   {x, -1, 1, .01} , {y, -1, 1, .01}], 1],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction :> (If[# < 0,
     Red,
     ColorData["RoseColors"][2 #]] &) ]
```

[image]

note we need to know the data range and manually scale for the color. In this case the positive values are in range `0-1/2` so multiply by `2` to get `0-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have asked another question which I think you could help to find the answer. Could you please?

Comment: I have aked the question in comments in below link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145213/solving-6th-order-equation-numerically

Comment: I think you meant `ColorFunctionScaling->False` in the text of the answer (the code is fine).

Comment: @yohbs yes thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Mesh` functionality also, keeping the automatic color scaling if you use the (apparently undocumented for this function) `MeshShading` option

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] - 1/2}, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 
     1, .05}], 1];

ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Automatic}]
```

[image]